# While migrating from CRA v5 to Vite I'm getting " import_fs2.default is null" while using "vite"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

I'm trying to migrate team project from CRA to Vite, but it's quite problematic for now

Now, when I managed to launch development env or serve env, I'm facing "import_fs2.default is null", which comes from graphql.macro

Technically, I could replace it with codegen, but given there isn't too much time for it, is there workaround?

Note I am using nodePolyfills if that matters and still I am getting this error

Console devtools highlights this: [highlighted line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6khH.png)

Error: [error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLCEF.png)

Vite config:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { defineConfig, UserConfigExport } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

const config = defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    nodePolyfills({
      // Whether to polyfill `node:` protocol imports.
      protocolImports: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
      '~antd': './node_modules/antd',
    },
  },
  base: '',
  build: {
    outDir: 'build',
    manifest: 'asset-manifest.json',
    assetsDir: 'static',
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1024,
  },
});

export default config;
```

I expected to graphql.macro work properly with vite

Technically, it build without errors, but launching is a different story

Comment: Update: just use graphql-loader of vite and it works good

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer

Just use vite loader for graphQL and changed loader calls to ES6 import